# how can I instantiate a template class in java in a certain way?

Tags: java, templates

I have a template class in Java, such as ArrayList. I want to create a class that extends the template class, while fixing SomeType to some type. Later, I want to be able to pass the non-templated new class as an argument to methods that originally accepted ArrayList. Is that possible?
Thanks.

Comment: I don't know how to create a class with fixed type from a generic class...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you can.  Check out [this post at JavaRanch](http://www.coderanch.com/t/407153/java/java/do-extend-ArrayList-way)

What you're looking for is

```
public class MyList extends ArrayList<String>{
    //code
}
```